# Visual Studio and automatic object creation using class factory in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, object, factory-pattern

I am trying to make a framework in C++ using Visual Studio 2010 where I can create objects at the same time as class definition of lots of derived classes. I have been reading a bit on this, and understand the the factory pattern can be used. I however do not manage to get it working.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class TestCase;

std::vector<TestCase*> testcases;

class base
{
public:
    static void init();
};

template<class T>
class TestcaseFactory// : public base
{
public:
    TestcaseFactory()
    {
        testcases.push_back(new T());
    }
private:
};


class TestCase
{
public:
    virtual void id() = 0;
};

#define TESTCASE(derived)\
class derived; \
TestcaseFactory<derived> testcase_##derived(); \
class derived : public TestCase

TESTCASE(derived1)
{
    void id() {std::cout << "derived 1" << std::endl;}
};

TESTCASE(derived2)
{
    void id() {std::cout << "derived 2" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < testcases.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        testcases[i]->id();
    }
    getchar( );
}
```

and would have expected the loop in `main()` to call the two created objects and print

```
derived1
derived2
```

However nothing happens. For some reason the code in the `#define` is never reached. I can not figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TestcaseFactory<derived> testcase_##derived();
```

This line declares a function, not a variable. It's a variant of the (most)  [vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) of C++ - if it *can* be a declaration, it is.